# How to have Finder display file Size in fixed units such as MB or KB?

Tags: macos, finder

The default behavior of Finder will show file Size in bytes, KB, MB, GB depending on the file size.

Is there a way to have Finder display the file Size in a fixed unit such as MB or KB?

(This makes it easier to tell approximate file size at a quick glance simply by how many digits wide the file size is).

Comment: Amen, huge files don’t stand out enough. One thing Windows Explorer gets right.